# Jquery Fancy Box Error 404

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, fancybox

I am using JQuery FancyBox and when I click on the small image to get bigger it keeps on saying error 404..

The code that I am doing is this:

```
<a class="fancybox-buttons" data-fancybox-group="button" href="images/gallery/1_b.png" style="margin-right:100px;"><img src="images/gallery/1_s.png" alt="" /></a>

<a class="fancybox-buttons" data-fancybox-group="button" href="images/gallery/2_b.png" style="margin-right:100px;"><img src="images/gallery/2_s.png" alt="" /></a>
```

For some reason when I see the source of the page it display as follows:

```
images/Skeleton/images/gallery/1_b.png 404 (Not Found) 
images/Skeleton/images/gallery/2_b.png 404 (Not Found)
```

The version I am using is jquery.fancybox.js?v=2.1.5.

Javascript code as follows:

```
<!-- Add Button helper (this is optional) -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.css?v=1.0.5" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.js?v=1.0.5"></script>

<!-- Add Thumbnail helper (this is optional) -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.css?v=1.0.7" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.js?v=1.0.7"></script>

<!-- Add Media helper (this is optional) -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-media.js?v=1.0.6"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            /*
             *  Simple image gallery. Uses default settings
             */

            $('.fancybox').fancybox();

            /*
             *  Different effects
             */

            // Change title type, overlay closing speed
            $(".fancybox-effects-a").fancybox({
                helpers: {
                    title : {
                        type : 'outside'
                    },
                    overlay : {
                        speedOut : 0
                    }
                }
            });

            // Disable opening and closing animations, change title type
            $(".fancybox-effects-b").fancybox({
                openEffect  : 'none',
                closeEffect : 'none',

                helpers : {
                    title : {
                        type : 'over'
                    }
                }
            });

            // Set custom style, close if clicked, change title type and overlay color
            $(".fancybox-effects-c").fancybox({
                wrapCSS    : 'fancybox-custom',
                closeClick : true,

                openEffect : 'none',

                helpers : {
                    title : {
                        type : 'inside'
                    },
                    overlay : {
                        css : {
                            'background' : 'rgba(238,238,238,0.85)'
                        }
                    }
                }
            });

            // Remove padding, set opening and closing animations, close if clicked and disable overlay
            $(".fancybox-effects-d").fancybox({
                padding: 0,

                openEffect : 'elastic',
                openSpeed  : 150,

                closeEffect : 'elastic',
                closeSpeed  : 150,

                closeClick : true,

                helpers : {
                    overlay : null
                }
            });

            /*
             *  Button helper. Disable animations, hide close button, change title type and content
             */

            $('.fancybox-buttons').fancybox({
                openEffect  : 'none',
                closeEffect : 'none',

                prevEffect : 'none',
                nextEffect : 'none',

                closeBtn  : false,

                helpers : {
                    title : {
                        type : 'inside'
                    },
                    buttons : {}
                },

                afterLoad : function() {
                    this.title = 'Image ' + (this.index + 1) + ' of ' + this.group.length + (this.title ? ' - ' + this.title : '');
                }
            });


            /*
             *  Thumbnail helper. Disable animations, hide close button, arrows and slide to next gallery item if clicked
             */

            $('.fancybox-thumbs').fancybox({
                prevEffect : 'none',
                nextEffect : 'none',

                closeBtn  : false,
                arrows    : false,
                nextClick : true,

                helpers : {
                    thumbs : {
                        width  : 50,
                        height : 50
                    }
                }
            });

            /*
             *  Media helper. Group items, disable animations, hide arrows, enable media and button helpers.
            */
            $('.fancybox-media')
                .attr('rel', 'media-gallery')
                .fancybox({
                    openEffect : 'none',
                    closeEffect : 'none',
                    prevEffect : 'none',
                    nextEffect : 'none',

                    arrows : false,
                    helpers : {
                        media : {},
                        buttons : {}
                    }
                });

            /*
             *  Open manually
             */

            $("#fancybox-manual-a").click(function() {
                $.fancybox.open('1_b.png');
            });

            $("#fancybox-manual-b").click(function() {
                $.fancybox.open({
                    href : 'iframe.html',
                    type : 'iframe',
                    padding : 5
                });
            });

            $("#fancybox-manual-c").click(function() {
                $.fancybox.open([
                    {
                        href : '1_b.png',
                        title : 'My title'
                    }, {
                        href : '2_b.png',
                        title : '2nd title'
                    }, {
                        href : '3_b.png'
                    }
                ], {
                    helpers : {
                        thumbs : {
                            width: 75,
                            height: 50
                        }
                    }
                });
            });


        });
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
        .fancybox-custom .fancybox-skin {
            box-shadow: 0 0 50px #222;
        }

        body {
            max-width: 700px;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }
</style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try doing

```
/images/gallery/1_b.png
/images/gallery/2_b.png
```

Notice the '/' at the beginning.
If your images folder is in the root directory, that will work.

EDITED ANSWER

Comment: You're better off losing the `404 (Not Found)`s from that answer.

Comment: The thing is that images are in this folder images/gallery/1_b.png. I don't know where the other part is coming from

Comment: I have another can I ask it here or should I post another question

Comment: it's best to post another question so that other people can also observe and help out

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57151/discussion-between-keith-spiteri-and-andrew-matthew).